# NTC Temprature Formula

Tags: sensor, thermistor

Below I attached an NTC sensor circuit, my question is how can I simply convert analog voltage values to temprature values. I saw some formulas but they seem complex. Can someone share formulas where the input is a Voltage signal and/or other constants, and the output is just temprature?

[image]

Comment: The relationship for resistance vs temperature should be in the thermistor's datasheet.  Then use formula for voltage divider.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Nick. Whıch formula are you talkıng about. Can you pls share a formula for a specefic ntc; input is Vout and other constants, output is just T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula ([Steinhart-Hart equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhart%E2%80%93Hart_equation)). Yes, it involves computation of transcendental functions, but it's one line with any C compiler.

On the other hand, you can simply use a lookup table. Say you have a 10-bit ADC, which has only 1024 distinct output codes. Simply **precalculate** the temperature for each of the 1024 codes *once* on a PC using your favorite programming language and spit out a table that you can include in your firmware program.

If you happen to have a very high resolution N-bit ADC you can have a smaller table than \$2^N\$ elements and interpolate using simple linear interpolation, cubic splines or whatever method suits your fancy.

Edit: [Here](http://www.vishay.com/docs/29049/ntcle100.pdf) is a proper datasheet for a thermistor. You can find the (extended) Steinhart-Hart parameters in the datasheet (A, B, C, D) and simply plug them into the equation to find the temperature for any given resistance.

To find a resistance from a ratiometric ADC code, you know that Vout = Vref\$\cdot\$Rt/(Rt +3K\$\Omega\$). 
Solve this for Rt(Vout). You know that the code will be Code = \$2^N \cdot \frac {V_{OUT}}{Vref}\$ for a unipolar ratiometric ADC, so you can solve that for Vout(Code) and substitute in for Rt(Code). Then use Steinhart-Hart to calculate T(Code). Very simple.

Comment: Thanks Spehro but i couldnt understand Steinhart–Hart equation, it seems i will find A,B and C from datasheet, what about R. I said in questıon that i have only Vout i have datasheet of 10k NTC sensor. Can you pls share formula or give link just that simple.

Comment: Where is the link for your datasheet?

Comment: What can't you understand about Steinhart-Hart? A, B, C, (D) are constants, ln() is a function. Rref in the Vishay equation is R25 (10K in your case).

Comment: Ok. The equation is: {1\T} = A + B \ln(R) + C [\ln(R)]^3 ,
So what will be R ? Where is Vout ?

Comment: If you're concerned about measurement accuracy, you should use `ratiometric` ADC configuration. Don't assume the +5V supply is exactly 5.00V, it will not be accurate. Connect to VREF voltage reference instead of +5V supply. Then the absolute voltage you measure doesn't matter, only the ratio Vout/Vref, which depends on the ratio 3kohm/R.

Comment: See my edit above to calculate the temperature for any Vout (what you call TEMP).

Comment: "To find a resistance from a ratiometric ADC code, you know that Vout = Vref⋅Rt/(Rt +3KΩ). Solve this for Rt(Vout)." Yes, can be solved Rt, then what you suggest use lookup table or another formulation to use Rt and get T ? By the way Vref is 5V right ?

Comment: Either Steinhart-Hart or use a lookup table, your choice. Either one is usually fast enough, but LUT will be faster and might be smaller code.

Comment: Spehro, i also have pt -200e thermistor . Can you give suggestion about how to read it . Thanks .

Comment: For Pt RTDs use the [Callendar-Van Dusen equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callendar%E2%80%93Van_Dusen_equation) rather than Steinhart-Hart, but usually you'll need more circuitry than shown here. It's also quite easy to linearize an RTD.

Answer (score 1):

As nick says there is probably a table available for the thermistor which gives the resistance against temperature.

I would put this table in excel and calculate the for each temperature in 5 - 10 degree steps.

Include the results of this table in your software that will do the conversion.

In your software you should read the voltage using the processor A/D then a linear search of the table to find the two table values that surround the voltage you have measured. (very rarely you will get an act match so you need to deal with that.

Then do a linear interpolation between these two values depending upon the actual voltage you are measuring.

It is better to do the measurement radiometrically where you calculate the A/D output in excel (i.e. the actual binary value you will get).

You may also want to include an adjustable offset to calibrate the temperature because there will be a tolerance of the thermistor.